# Is it sufficient to put my configuration file under /etc/logrotate.d to logrotate?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, logrotate

I currently have a Django app running on Ubuntu under Apache.  The Apache logs are generated at:

```
/home/user/django/myproject/log/apache_access.log
/home/user/django/myproject/log/apache_error.log
```

The above logs are currently growing very rapidly, so I create a configuration file for logrotate and place it under `/etc/logrotate.d`.  The configuration is called: `my_app`, it's path is `/etc/logrotate.d/my_app`.  The content of `my_app` is:

```
/home/user/django/myproject/log/*.log{
    daily
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
                fi
        endscript
}
```

Will the above configuration logrotate the apache log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is all you need to do.

When logrotate runs the main configuration file includes all the configuration fragements in the logrotate.d folder.

See:

```
/etc/logrotate.conf
...
# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Comment: Of course, you should make sure the include line is NOT commented out in your install